Best Approach for Discord OAuth2.0 Login with Android WebView?
Previously, I implemented OAuth2.0 login directly through the web so that the app could handle the login without relying on an external web browser.
Now, I am trying to implement Discord OAuth2.0 login using Android WebView. However, I am aware that there are security concerns with using WebView for OAuth2.0 authentication.
To address these issues, I am considering the following approach: instead of using the WebView for Discord login, I plan to redirect users to an external web browser for the login process, then retrieve the token by redirecting back to the app using a deep link. Would this be a secure and effective approach?
Furthermore, I am planning to use the token obtained through the browser to communicate with the WebView via a bridge. Is this the correct way to implement this?
Lastly, do I need the Discord Client Secret during this process, or is it unnecessary?
